# Average Time Calculation on SQL for App Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

So I am posting this after seraching alot of SO queries and answers.
I have a table that gives the booktime, pickup time. I want to calculate the average timedifference between the two timestamps group on hourly basis and area-wise.The desired output is given below
This all needs to be done in SQL

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Hour</td>
  <td>Order#</td>
  <td>AverageResponseTime</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>20</td>
  <td>15:13</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>02:45</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>120</td>
  <td>01:20</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>24</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>19:05</td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Help others to help you [mcve]

Comment: How about some sample data ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
select
    AreaName,
    datepart(hour, BookTime) as BookTimeHour,
    (AVG(Datediff(second, booktime, pickuptime))/60.0) as AvgTimeInMinutes
from @MyTable
group by
    AreaName,
    datepart(hour,BookTime);
```